# OpenXML, SAX, and Simply Reading an Xlsx file

Tags: c#, datatable, openxml, xlsx

I have been struggling to find a solution on how to read a large xlsx file with OpenXml.  I have tried the microsoft samples without luck.  I simply need to read an excel file into a DataTable in c#.  I am not concerned with value types in the datatable, everything can be stored as a string values.

The samples I have found so far don't retain the structure of the spreadsheet and only return the values of the cells.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open xml SDK can be a little hard to understand.  However, I have found it useful to use http://simpleooxml.codeplex.com/ this code plex project.  It adds a thin layer over the sdk to more easily parse through excel files and work with styles.

Then you can use something like the following with their worksheet reader to recurse through and grab the values you want

```
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = Utility.StreamToMemory(xslxTemplate);
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(ms, true))
{
    IEnumerable<Sheet> sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>();
    if (sheets.Count() == 0)
    {
        // The specified worksheet does not exist.
        return null;
    }
    string relationshipId = sheets.First().Id.Value;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
    string myval =WorksheetReader.GetCell("A", 0, worksheetPart).CellValue.InnerText;
    // Put in a loop to go through contents of document
}
```

Comment: I need to be able to read the excel file via the SAX method.  Does simpleooxml support that?

Comment: I think it will work fine.  The simpleooxml is really just a thin layer over the regular items.  I just include the project in it entirety and jump in and make any adjustments to the underlying layer if needed.  It returns the raw XML objects in most instances.  At the very least it should point you toward the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can get DataTable this way:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false))
{
    DataTable data = ToDataTable(spreadsheet, "Employees");
}
```

This method will read Excel sheet data as DataTable

```
public DataTable ToDataTable(SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet, string worksheetName)
{
    var workbookPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart;

    var sheet = workbookPart
        .Workbook
        .Descendants<Sheet>()
        .FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == worksheetName);

    var worksheetPart = sheet == null
        ? null
        : workbookPart.GetPartById(sheet.Id) as WorksheetPart;

    var dataTable = new DataTable();

    if (worksheetPart != null)
    {
        var sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

        foreach (Row row in sheetData.Descendants<Row>())
        {
            var values = row
                .Descendants<Cell>()
                .Select(cell =>
                {
                    var value = cell.CellValue.InnerXml;
                    if (cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
                    {
                        value = workbookPart
                            .SharedStringTablePart
                            .SharedStringTable
                            .ChildElements[int.Parse(value)]
                            .InnerText;
                    }
                    return (object)value;
                })
                .ToArray();

            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }
    }

    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that uses the DOM approach as opposed to the SAX approach which will lead to performance issues with large Excel files.  This is assuming you don't run out of memory first since this methodology requires the entire object structure to be first copied into memory.